# Plotting GAMs on Response Scale with Multiple Smooth and Linear Terms

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Here is a quick reproducible script to plot GAMs on the response scale instead of the "smooth" scale for a single term via the 'mgcv' R package.

I made the below script for a friend who is using GAMs for his PhD. work in evolutionary biology. I use the Hubble data from the 'gamair' R package simply as a demonstration.

```
##### Example of GAM Plotting on Response Scale #####

### Load required packages ###

library(gamair)
library(mgcv)

### Data setup ###

data(hubble)
hubble # 24 observations

x <- hubble$x # predictor
y <- hubble$y # response


### GAM setup ###

mod <- gam(y ~ s(x)) # thin plate GAM with k = 10 degrees of freedom (by default)

plot(mod) # smooth term is on y-axis

### GAM prediction ###

pd <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 24, by = 0.1)) # fine grid of points
pr <- predict(mod, newdata = pd, type = "response", se = TRUE) # get predicted response values from GAM


### GAM plotting ###

with(hubble, plot(x, y, ylim = c(0, 2000))) # plot data
lines(pd$x, pr$fit) # plot predicted fit
lines(pd$x, pr$fit - qnorm(0.975) * pr$se.fit, lty = 2) # plot lower 95% CI endpoint
lines(pd$x, pr$fit + qnorm(0.975) * pr$se.fit, lty = 2) # plot upper 95% CI endpoint
```

The above script works like a charm. The difficulty arises when the GAM contains multiple terms, even though only a single term is plotted at a time.

By a GAM with multiple terms I mean something like

```
mod <- gam(y ~ s(x) + z).
```

Here 'z' is linear term (not a smooth term).

**Could someone (@gavinsimpson?) provide a quick example of plotting such a GAM on the response scale?**

I haven't been able to find such an example online or in Simon Wood's great book on GAMs and mgcv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the model contains `z` then the effect of `x` estimated by the model is that given `z` is in the model. Hence the fitted response is the additive sum of the two effects, and we can't talk generally about the estimated values of the response for a range of values of `x` without also stating the value of `z`.

For Gaussian models, you can just add on the intercept in `plot.gam()` to shift around the smooth curve on the y-axis. See argument `shift` to `plot.gam()`. This assumes that as per the example `x` and `z` are unrelated in the model, and furthermore some value of `z` (in this case I think 0 as it is a linear term not subject to identifiability constraints).

A more general solution is just to predict from the model at a grid of values over `x` while holding `z` constant at some representative value, say its mean or median.

Here's a full example of doing this by hand:

```
library("mgcv")
library("ggplot2")

set.seed(1)
df <- gamSim()
m <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = df, method = "REML")

new_data <- with(df, expand.grid(x2 = seq(min(x2), max(x2), length = 200),
                                 x0 = median(x0),
                                 x1 = median(x1),
                                 x3 = median(x3)))

ilink <- family(m)$linkinv
pred <- predict(m, new_data, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
pred <- cbind(pred, new_data)
pred <- transform(pred, lwr_ci = ilink(fit - (2 * se.fit)),
                        upr_ci = ilink(fit + (2 * se.fit)),
                        fitted = ilink(fit))

ggplot(pred, aes(x = x2, y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr_ci, ymax = upr_ci), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line()
```

producing

[image]

That script should be fine for any of the standard `family` options in *mgcv*, but you'll have to take careful note of what `predict()` returns for some of the fancier families in *mgcv*.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Gavin's answer, I find `emmeans` offers the same functionality while being easier to remember. It also offers a simple interface for changing significance level or adjusting for multiple comparisons (see `?confint.emmGrid` for details).

````
library("mgcv")
library("ggplot2")
library("emmeans")

set.seed(1)
df <- gamSim()
m <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = df, method = "REML")

at.list = with(df, list(
    x2=seq(min(x2), max(x2), length = 200),
     x0 = median(x0),
     x1 = median(x1),
     x3 = median(x3)
))

## new method: prediction + CI with emmeans
pred.emm <- as.data.frame(
    emmeans(m, ~x2, at=at.list, adjust='none', level=0.95)
)

## minor modifications to plot: change variable names
p1 <- (
    ggplot(pred.emm, aes(x = x2, y = emmean))
    + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL), alpha = 0.2)
    + geom_line()
)

## manually compute CI, modified from @Gavin's answer
new_data <- with(at.list, data.frame(
    x0, x1, x2, x3
))

quant <- qnorm(1-0.05/2)
ilink <- family(m)$linkinv
pred <- predict(m, new_data, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
pred <- cbind(pred, new_data)
pred <- transform(pred, lwr_ci = ilink(fit - (quant * se.fit)),
                        upr_ci = ilink(fit + (quant * se.fit)),
                        fitted = ilink(fit))


## compare CI between methods
head(cbind( 
    pred[, c('lwr_ci', 'upr_ci')], 
    pred.emm[, c('lower.CL', 'upper.CL')]
))
```
````