# Showing raw data behind smooths from GAMs with multiple predictors

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am using GAMs to visualize partial, potentially non-linear influences of a continuous predictor (x) across a categorical predictor (fac). I say partial because I am considering including an additional covariate (z) which is known to have a linear influence on the response (y).

SO, the model has the structure:

**y ~ fac + s(x, by=fac) + z**

I am comfortable calculating the partial smooth effects, following [Plotting GAMs on Response Scale with Multiple Smooth and Linear Terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471267/plotting-gams-on-response-scale-with-multiple-smooth-and-linear-terms)

**My question is** whether it would make sense to show raw data on a plot showing a partial smooth. I am keen on showing raw data alongside model outputs, but given potential collinearities between x and z, I expect that the a plot of the fitted smooth (fitted vs. x) could (in some cases) could be swayed by un-visualized influences from z, causing a reader/reviewer to think that the fit is poorer than it is.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!